# intl phone field in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using intl phone field inside a form I just want to validate the intll field only on interaction
But if the field is empty it should allow me to submit form

but unfortunately that's not the case it shows default message Invalid Phone Number I even can't able to remove that message

here is my code

```
SizedBox(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  IntlPhoneField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    controller: _phoneController,
                    initialCountryCode: selectedRegion,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')),
                    ],
                    onChanged: (phone) {},
                    onCountryChanged: (Country country) {
                      selectedRegion = country.code;
                      countryCode = country.dialCode;
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: try implement `onValidate( )` function

Comment: and onValidate() what should be the properties because I have tried the folloiwng but the default message wont change like if null or empty then some my message

Comment: means remove the message while typing ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this.

disableLengthCheck: false,

this will allow you to submit the form even if the phone number is empty; if it's not, it will do the validation.